# cannot index in elasticsearch

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

i am using python elasticsearch library for creating index in elasticsearch

for the first time its working fine . But afterwards i cannot create any index . this is what i tried.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 

es = Elasticsearch()

es.index(index="account", doc_type="profile", id=2, body={"name":"thameem"})
```

for the first this is working

but when i index with same values it gives this error .

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthorizationException: TransportError(403, u'cluster_block_exception', u'blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)]
```

later on i cannot 
add anymore documents in the same index . But i can create new index easily. So what is the problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

As written in ES Github this is a bug https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/13685

Users have solved with this command:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://[YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT]:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```